# GSuite OAuth 2.0 Invalid Scopes Grafana

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

So, I've followed the documentation found [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/google/).
I then created an oauth 2.0 web application [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).
After I took the client ID and I used it in the Manage API Client Access for the [GSuite Admin](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome) following the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en) to add the scopes. However, when I go to my app and I hit the "Sign in with Google" I get a:

> 400 Invalid Scopes
>
> {invalid=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']}

Both of the scopes above have been added to the Manage API Client Access screens.

Any steps I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Github pipeline + docker build args with spaces are a no-go. Use secrets and envs.

Found the solution. The issue was that I was defining my scopes in the CI pipeline (github yml) and passing it to my docker file as a build arg which was being converted to an ENV. This didn't work well since there was a space in the string. I moved the two scopes to a github secret and exported it as an ENV which is then secure env'd in the docker file.